# как узнать количество символов в файле c#

Tags: c#

как узнать количество символов в файле c#

Comment: Каких символов? Но вообще GetFileSize()

Comment: всех что есть к примеру как string.length

Comment: @whoami как String.Length - только прочитав весь файл как одну большую строку, и вызвав у нее String.Length

Answer (score 6):

Что бы не загружать весь файл целиком в память можно так:

```
var charCount = 0;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"path_to_file", detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true))
{
    while (reader.Read() > -1)
    {
        charCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, но тогда уж лучше в буфер блоками читать, а не посимвольно.

Comment: Так StreamReader по блокам в память и читает, одна из перегрузок конструктора позволяет этот буфер задать. По умолчанию 4096 байт.

Comment: Мне кажется всё-таки цикл наподобие `char[] buff = new char[buffSize]; int cntRead = 0; while ((cntRead = reader.Read(buff, 0, buffSize)) > 0) charCount += cntRead;` быстрее проскочит.

Comment: Возможно, не проверял. В ответе я показал работающий пример и достаточно простой для понимания, а вот как его развить дальше дело  программиста.

Answer (score 4):

Читаем файл (по умолчанию, кодировка `UTF-8`):

```
var txt = File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
```

После этого смотрим `txt.Length`.